# My .cshtml page does not open

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error  could not load file or assembly

```
microsoft.visualstudio.projectsystem.dotnet.14.0
version=14.0.0.0,culture=neutral,,public key token=b03f5f7f11a3a 
or one of it's dependancies.the system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Reinstall the DotNetCore. it should fix your problem.

Comment: Actualy I don't have install DotNetCore. I am only update my .NetFramework 4.6.1 after that I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of **microsoft.visualstudio.projectsystem.dotnet** in packages.config and see if it is different then the version of your DLL. If the problem still persists, run the code

> update-package -reinstall

in your **Package Manager Console.**

Let me know for further problems regarding this.